# Zero the elements of a vector past a cumulative sum using matrix notation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, cumulative-sum

I have a vector `x = [x_1, ..., x_n]` and a threshold `t`.

Define the cumulative sum: `S_m = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_m`.

Let `j` be such that `S_{j-1} < t <= S_j.`

I want to set all elements `x_i` with `i > j` to 0 in this vector, and `x_j` to `t - S_{j-1}`. Is there a way to write this operation in matrix-vector multiplication?

Comment: edit to reflect that I'm looking for matrix-vector multiplication with a view towards vectorisation

Comment: By matrix-vector, do you mean a matrix composed of n vectors like x and a vector of n thresholds?

Comment: If you mean implementing the transformation of x strictly as a matrix multiplication, the answer is no. A matrix multiplication is a linear transformation, but the transformation you define is not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 4, 2])
>>> t = 13

>>> S = x.cumsum()
>>> j = np.argmax(t < S)
>>> x[j:] = 0
>>> x[j] = t - S[j-1]

>>> x
array([0, 3, 5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Should it be like `j = np.argmax(t <= S)`?

Comment: The case for equality is covered by the last assignment to `x[j]`. In fact, results are the same with `<` or `<=`, except that it fails for `t=0` when `<=` is used.

Comment: I should have been more precise in my question, which I've edit now. I'm looking for a matrix-vector multiplication operation that gives me the resulting vector, so it can be vectorised nicely.